# Twig - get the number of words from a string

Tags: php, string, twig

I am using craft cms, that uses twig templating, and would like to get the number of words from the string. I have tried with using the PHP function `str_word_count()` :

```
       {% for entry in entries %}
          <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            <div class="media-object">
              <div class="small-4 columns">
                <div class="media-object-section">
                  <img src= "{{ entry.topImage.first().getUrl('square') }}">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small-8 columns">
                <div class="media-object-section main-section">
                  <h4>{{ entry.title }}</h4>
                  {% set numberOfWords = str_word_count(entry.summary) %}
                  <p>{{ entry.summary |split(" ")|slice(0, 15)|join(" ") }}</p>
                  <p>{{ entry.dateUpdated | date('j. F Y') }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        {% endfor %}
```

But, I got an error:

> Unknown "str_word_count" function.

How can I get the number of words from the string in the twig template?

Comment: whats your php version?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
{% set numberOfWords = entry.summary|split(' ')|length %}
```

[Split](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) function will split your string to array by given parameter (space in this case) and [length](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/length.html) will count array elements.

Comment: what if you have two part words ?

Comment: Then my answer would count it as single. For example "foo-bar" would result in 1 word. But even [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) by definition would count it as 1: "For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters."

Comment: i was thinking more about two parts words without "-", like "ping pong" for exemple

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom extension and make use of any PHP functions inside: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, as suggested by Tomas,
I wrote my own twig (filter) function for this case:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\TwigExtensions;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class TwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{

    /**
     * this is needed
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'your_twig_extensions';
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('strWordCount', array($this, 'strWordCount')),
        );
    }


  /**
     * count Words in string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function strWordCount($text = null)
    {
        return str_word_count($text);
    }

}
```